# Which preposition to use when two years are separated by a hyphen?

Tags: prepositions, hyphens

> The implementation of socialism in the Soviet Union caused a famine in
> 1930. (1)

> The implementation of socialism in the Soviet Union caused a famine in
> 1930-1933. (2)

I know that sentence (1) is correct, but I don't know if sentence (2) is correct. If there's two years separated by a hyphen, can I use "in" as the preposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific grammar rule here, but the meaning is carried by "between":

> ... between 1930-1933

The hyphen would be read aloud as "and".

In many cases you'd be better using " ... from 1930 to 1933" instead of a hyphen or rephrasing  "in the years 1930-1933" or if the existence of a famine is well known "... caused the famine of 1930-1933".  (if you are writing for a specialist audience, you might assume that they already know of the famine, so "the famine" is appropriate)

Comment: I only read the hyphen as "to" so your first answer is incorrect to my Canadian ears.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use "in" there. "In" is used for one specific year, not a span of years, unless you say so specifically:

> ... caused a famine in **the years** 1930-1933.

Other possible phrasings include:

> ... caused a famine between 1930 and 1933
> ... caused a famine from 1930 to 1933